# Switching from SQLPlus to SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Currently we are using SQLPlus and searching for table contents via Putty in our Project. Is there any way we can migrate to SQL Developer, so that writing the queries and remembering them is no longer a pain.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: What you tried? What you implemented? What issues you faced? This is not a place to ask ideas. First study this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "*is there any way can migrate to SQL Developer?*" - yes of course. Download it, run it and enter your statements there. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Both SQLPlus and SQLDeveloper are tools, which you can use to access an Oracle database. There is nothing to migrate, you simply start to use the tool you like. You can use them even in parallel, these are practically clients of the database, having no impact to each other. So, just do it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use both SQLPlus and SQL Developer with some regularity.  They serve different purposes.  If I just want to look at some table, I use SQLPlus.  If I need to prepare complicated data for somebody else, I use SQL Developer.  I expect that no matter where you go, you will find that queries will be of similar difficulty.  I trust you have your editor defined in SQLPlus, that is basically what makes SQLPlus usable.  When I have anything of any complexity, I prepare the SQL in another window in my text editor and copy and paste into the SQLPlus or SQL Developer window.

I just downloaded SQL Developer using this link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

and after decompressing, I started using it.  The only complication was turning my SQLPlus connect string into the data required by SQL Developer.

For discussion, in sqlplus, I use scott/tiger@data.base.  This username and password was functional for SQL Developer but I needed to lookup the database string in the tnsnames.ora file at:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tns_names.ora
```

When I searched for data.base, I found the record:

```
DATA.BASE=
(DESCRIPTION=
 (ADDRESS=
  (PROTOCOL=TCP)
  (HOST=mydatabase.host.mycorp.com)
  (PORT=1521)
 )
 (CONNECT_DATA=
  (SERVER=dedicated)
  (SERVICE_NAME=mydatabase.mycorp.com)
  (failover_mode=
   (type=select)
   (method=basic)
   (retries=20)
   (delay=10))
 ))
```

When I created a new database connection, it prompted me for the following:

```
Connection Name:   My database for test
Username:          scott
Password:          tiger
save password:     (I checked this since the tiger password never changes)
Connection Type:   Basic
Role:              Default
Hostname:          mydatabase.host.mycorp.com
Port:              1521
Service Name:      mydatabase.mycorp.com
```

I then clicked on the test button and I got a "Status: Success" so I then clicked on the save button.

Getting it to run a query took a little while the first time but if you type alt-F10, it prompts you for one of your connections.  In the resulting query builder, you can type your query and press the arrow/green triangle/run icon at the top to execute.  I just did:

```
select tname from tab;
```

to see a list of my tables but something like

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

might be more generic.

Like I said, they serve different purposes.  Sqlplus comes up NOW on my Unix machine and SQL developer comes up after like 10-15 seconds my PC.  Since I am always impatient, this is a factor for me.

The short answer to your question "Is there anyway..." is "Yes."

I hope this helps.

Comment: If I have the IP of my Database along with username and password. How can I setup a connection. Do I need some other information and what should be the connection type.

Comment: More?  Yes. To access the database with SQL Developer, you will have to convert the connect string into its pieces by studying the tnsnames.ora file.  If you connect with this/pass@data.base, the this and pass parts will stay the same but you will need to pull the data.base part out of the tnsnames.ora file.  If you are on unix, this will be in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tns_names.ora  Getting to the file really is that easy.  Type ls -l $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tns_names.ora   and see what happens.